# nlogn complexity implementation Python

Tags: python, time-complexity

I tried to implement an algorithm with `O(n log n)` complexity. Everything works until the check for the `loop_temp` variable equaling `1`. It seems that either the `loop_temp` variable is not being divided by `2` and re-stored in its own variable, or the checking condition on the `while` loop for `loop_variable > 1` is not working. Initially I thought it may have been the differences between floating point comparisons with integer comparisons, but it does not seem to be the case. `2.0 == 2` and `1.0` is not greater than `1`.

I'm aware this type of implementation only works for certain values e.g 2,4,8 because the rounding function is missing. However, it's just an example.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
def nlogn_iteration(input, for_loop):
    """
    nlog(n) complexity refers to the following outputs:
    8*2^3operations = 8inputs
    16*2^4operations = 16inputs
    etc...
    """
    loop_temp = input #Loop temporary variable in order to stop the while loop, creates O(log(n)) complexity
    #For loop permanent variable in order to create the O(n) complexity

    while(loop_temp>1):
        if(loop_temp==1):
            print("Input value = 1")
        print("Input value", loop_temp)
        loop_temp = loop_temp/2
        for iteration in range(for_loop):
            print("Iteration no:", iteration)
        nlogn_iteration(loop_temp, for_loop)

#nlogn_iteration(8,8)
```

Comment: As a start, you need to rename your `input` variable, since it's a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) that means something specific in python. Also, what are you attempting to calculate here? What outputs do you expect for what inputs?

Comment: for that matter, `for_loop` is a really confusing variable name.

Comment: What's the point of the recursive call? Note, you say you want `O(N*log N)`, but you have *two* inputs to your function....

Comment: note, you can just do `for _ in range(n.bit_length()): for _ in range(n): ...`

Comment: or for that matter, `for i in range(int(math.log(n)*n)): ...`

Comment: Okay yes thats perfect, getting the the number of bits representation of the input_size. Thanks for that. Im not totally aware of the dictionary of functions tbh. Thanks for that

Comment: I can see that it also removes the additiona overhead from recusrive function calls.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
while(loop_temp>1):
    if(loop_temp==1):
```

The first conditional says "keep doing this so long as `loop_temp` is greater than one. Else quit." Since we know that once we reach the second conditional, the value *must* be higher than 1, we know `if(loop_temp==1)` will never evaluate as `true`.

You probably want something closer to:

```
while(loop_temp > 1):
    loop_temp = loop_temp / 2
    nlogn_iteration(loop_temp, for_loop)

if (loop_temp == 1):
    print(f"{loop_temp=}"
```

You also have numerous other problems. `input` is a [builtin function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input), which you should not re-assign to a variable without expecting strange behavior. `for_loop` as a variable is not doing anything other than triggering an unnecessary inner loop that will always output the same thing. Even your `while` loop is unnecessary since you're using a recursive function.

I suspect you're trying to count how many times you need to divide a number by 2 before reaching 1 recursively. That looks something like this:

```
def halving(starting_number, iterations: int = 0) -> int:
    # check your base case first in any recursive function
    if starting_number <= 1:
        return iterations
    # Take half using integer division (drops remainder)
    half = starting_number // 2
    # Increment the number of iterations we've gone through and make the recursive call.
    return halving(half, iterations + 1)
```

This yields the following in the REPL:

```
>>> halving(8)
3
```

I would note, however, that this is all `O(log n)` on the size of the input (`8` in this example). It would be difficult to do this in `O(n log n)` without being intentionally wasteful - unless there is some constraint to the problem of which I'm unaware.